# Change configuration options of a custom field

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-field-types

Is it possible to make a custom field and create additional customization options for when you add the column to a list?

If so, how?

Comment: What do you mean by additional customization options? Validations?

Comment: If you go to list settings, and click on a column there are the "additional column settings." I'm trying to make an extensible autocomplete field and was hoping I would be able to add settings in that area.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. It is another UserControl that implements an IFieldEditor interface. Once you have created the control and the field, you bind them together in the field definition xml.

Here is the step by step process https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj126861(v=office.14).aspx. Notice the FieldEditorUserControl in the fldtypes_InterestCalculatorField.xml file in the link above.